# ffmpeg display only video in Android

Tags: android, ffmpeg, sdl-2

I am Writing video player in android. So far i could able to capture the frames, with the help of av_read_frame and avcodec_decode_video2, and updating to SDL2.0. I have followed dranger tutorial02.c http://dranger.com/ffmpeg/  .

Sudo Code is :

```
 while (1)

   {
         1. Read packet
         2. check if video frame; if not Go to Step 3.
                2.1  if video frame, then update with SDL_UpdateYUVTexture,
         3. Handle SDL Event
         4. Clear the Renderer.
         5. Present Renderer. 
   }
```

I wonder, do i need to take care of  synchronization of video, dts/pts calculation while i need only to display video?

This scenario works well in the samsung, but not in other mobiles.

What woud be your advice?

Answer (score 0):

It depends. If you're ok with the fact that your video will a) play as fast as the device can decode it and b) will play with different speed on different devices and even on the same device depending on other processes, then you don't need to synchronize, and can just dump the frames as soon as they're decoded.

Otherwise you still need to synchronize the video output to PTS. Since you don't have audio, and won't have audio clock, your only option would be to synchronize the video to the system clocks which makes it simpler.

Comment: George, thanks for the reply, how it depends on other processes?. unless we get the frame, we can not display it?, so all it depends on when we get right?, then why pts ?

Comment: Unless you get a frame, you do not display it as there's nothing to display. And if you do, then use the PTS you get to know when to display this frame.

Comment: thanks george, that is where my question is. When i get the frame as soon as possible, why to consider PTS, as already i have a frame, let's say even if i calculate PTS, it should probably be a future time. that's means i m creating more latency right? kindly advice!!!

Comment: Because it you do not, the playback speed of your video would depend on the device performance. On a slow device you'd play maybe 1x, but on a fast device your video would play like 4x. So if you decode the PTS and it is in a future, you just store the frame in a queue, and show it when it is time.